# xampp php file upload error

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, xampp

I can't figure out what's going wrong with my file upload on php.

php code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['Loggedin']!="Yes") {
    header('location:index.php');
    exit();
}
require_once('Connect.php');

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "../htdocs/sites/tryouts/newgames/images/main-news/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$author=$_POST['author'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$bericht=$_POST['bericht'];



//Writes the information to the database
mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO nieuws (Nieuws_Author,Nieuws_Title,Nieuws_Image,Nieuws_Bericht)
VALUES ('$author', '$title', '$pic', '$bericht')") ;

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
  ?>
```

I get 2 errors:

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(../htdocs/sites/tryouts/newgames/images/main-news/bandicam
>   2014-05-2919-48-59-499.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   C:\Users\xammp\htdocs\sites\tryouts\newgames\addnewsscripts.php on
>   line 26

and

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\Users\xammp\tmp\php24D.tmp' to
>   '../htdocs/sites/tryouts/newgames/images/main-news/bandicam 2014-05-29
>   19-48-59-499.jpg' in
>   C:\Users\xammp\htdocs\sites\tryouts\newgames\addnewsscripts.php on
>   line 26 Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

I already have checked that php file upload is set on and the dir is:

> upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Users\xammp\tmp"

can you figure out what i am doing wrong?
probaly it is the directory where i want to place my images in but which target directory do i need to use?

Comment: You have Windows paths mixed in with Unix paths. Is this a Windows environment or not?

Comment: Yes windows 7 64 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if we have

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "../htdocs/sites/tryouts/newgames/images/main-news/";
```

And the error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   **'C:\Users\xammp\tmp\php24D.tmp'** to
>   **'../htdocs/sites/tryouts/newgames/images/main-news/bandicam** 2014-05-29
>   19-48-59-499.jpg' in
>   C:\Users\xammp\htdocs\sites\tryouts\newgames\addnewsscripts.php on
>   line 26 Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

I would say you need to change your path to something like

```
$target = "C:\Users\xammp\htdocs\sites\tryout\newgames\images\main-news\";
```